# Select in interface for better performance

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to optimize behavior of my web application.

I'm using interface as base for models, then I have controller, where methods from this interface are used.

For loading more datas to tables I'd need to use `Select` special for every model inheriting the interface (not to load all fields from database).

Here is code which is working:

```cs
public virtual JsonResult DbData(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
{ 
    var datalist = dbSetForDbData.GetAndSortDataForAJAX(model, true, out int recordsFiltered, out int recordsTotal); //get and sort data
```

when I'd like to have something like this:

```cs
public virtual JsonResult DbData(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
{ 
    var dataList = dbSetForDbData.Select(SelectDbData).GetAndSortDataForAJAX(model, true, out recordsFiltered, out recordsTotal); //get and sort data
```

I thought, that I'd use somethink like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, T>> SelectDbData = input=>IModel<T,TModel>.SelectForModel(input)
```

Where `IModel<T,TModel>` is my interface.

In interface I had this method:

```cs
public override FooModel SelectForModel(FooModel input)
{
    return new FooModel
    {
        Id = input.Id,
        Number = input.Number,
        ...
    };
}
```

But it does not work (expression cannot be translated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not break Expression chain. Everything should be Expression

```cs
Expression<Func<T, T>> SelectDbData = IModel<T,TModel>.SelectForModel();
```

```cs
public override Exppression<Func<FooModel, FooModel>> SelectForModel()
{
    return input => new FooModel
    {
        Id = input.Id,
        Number = input.Number,
        ...
    };
}
```